# wifi connected to android via laptop but internet is not coming

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager, android

I have started wifi in my ubuntu using [this process](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2009381) and is equivalent to [ap-hotspot](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGi0YjJQYsRYpOyTKjVloGYKtaWZg) and I am able to connect my rooted
android device to my laptop via wifi but I am not able to get Internet connection in my mobile phone
I use wired connection in my laptop.
If I start wifi in my windows 8 using the [connectify](http://www.connectify.me/), I am able to use internet in my mobile.
my wired connection is shared

[image]

I have gone through this question
[How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-share-your-internet-connection)