# How to share ethernet over wifi without creating access point?

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet, sharing

I have company internet with internal IP and proxy settings, I want to share this Ethernet connection over wifi, but creating accesspoint is somehow not working may be due to IP architecture, I want to share connection so that if my mobile use it over wifi, the computer thinks as if a browser on the same computer is accessing the internet (By forwarding or tunneling or something like that).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I know that method, as you perhaps know I cant create another network in the company network infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

For now, I can access my vm. so, this maybe contains errors or does not fit your environment.

1. Click the up & down arrows in right upper side and click "Edit Connections...".
2. It shows "Network Connections", select "Wireless" tab, and click "add" button.
3. In "Editing Wireless connection 1", change "Connection name:" as you want.
4. Change SSID as you want.
5. Mode must be Ad-hoc.
6. Click "Wireless Security", select "Security" and "Password"
7. Finally, connect your device with SSID you made.

[image]

Comment: My device does not seem to recognize ad-hoc network, however that still sets up network with distinct IP address to connected device. What i want is device connects to wifi but wifi draws the internet by disguising as browser on the computer (Ubuntu), by means of some work around.