# Tunnel internet through laptop to other pc

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, ethernet, subnet

Following setup:

I got a wireless network at home that my laptop connects to to access the internet. I also got an IOT2000 board, which is basically a small PC running Linux. My Router does not have any ethernet ports so I cant use the second interface of my IOT2000 to connect to it, and the IOT does not have WiFi. Now I want to set it up so that the IOT can use my laptops internet connection.

The only solution I found online was to change the ethernet mode on my laptop to "share connection with other computers." The problem is, I have to keep it at manual so I am in the same subnet as the IOT.

How do I have to set up my IOT and Laptop in order to get internet on the IOT and also keep the subnets? I attached a couple images showing the current setup and settings.

[image: IOT2000 /etc/network/interfaces]
[image: Laptop Ethernet settings]
[image: Network plan]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless)

Comment: Not a duplicate as this solution won't work with different subnets as far as I can tell

Comment: In my opinion iptables masquerading would be a solution here. I do not have experience in using iptables with Ubuntu. I usually do it with RedHat/CentOS, so I will not give you details how to do it. The main trick is to masquerade traffic on laptop comming from 192.168.200.0/24 and forward it to 192.168.1.1. Default gateway for IOT is 192.168.200.2. When responses come back, the connection tracking identifies these packets and forwards them back to 192.168.200.0/24. Look here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please also [edit] your question to highlight how you want the subnets to be set up? At the moment you mention it a single time at the end of a paratactic sentence where it's easy to miss. In the same way, it's easy to miss the different subnets in your diagram unless you know what to look for. Thanks.