# ethernet(wired connected) network share through hotspot

Tags: networking, 22.04, ethernet

I am on **ubuntu 22.04**. My machine is connected through **ethernet**. Now I want to ***share*** my internet through **hotspot** to **[pc & android]**. How can I do this?

I have tried through **nm-connection-editor**. But nothing happended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Connect & Share your Internet Connection (Wired & Wireless)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171914/how-to-connect-share-your-internet-connection-wired-wireless)

Comment: I will see this